# Entity forms : Can't assign the new field to parent 'group'

Tags: entities

I working on web based diary,

In the diary there are 21 days where every day is a Parent 'Group' with field type Vertical tab. Every day has 16 fields which are same for every day.

I am able to create successfully 17 days without any problem but after that I am not able to assign fields to any parent 'Group'.

after selecting parent and clinking save it reload the page without saving the configuration.

There is no error or any message to help identifying the problem, I am new with Drupal and don't have any idea why it is happening, I try Google and couldn't find any information that could help.

I was wondering if there is any way to find the logs and errors. Or if there is any limitation on the number of fields/group.

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Have you checked server's error.log and Drupal's /admin/reports/dblog ?

Comment: Hi Molot,
Thanks for reply, Yes I checked and there is noting.

Comment: So there is db log to check, and js console. Also, use `@` before my name if you want me to know you replied to me.

Comment: @Molot, Yes there is db log but with no error about any module.

I try using Firebug to check if I can get any error but noting come out.

Comment: Anyway... are you trying to create an entity with 336 fields? It's quite a lot for most setups. Considered making a "day" entity and using views to aggregate and display days?

Comment: @Mołot Exactly there are 21 days and each with 16 fields, Howe ever every day have the same 16 fields. I am new with Entity forms and I am not sure if there is any way where I can use the same fields for all groups.